# how do i send all my json parsed data from one activity to another activity with intents

Tags: android

In my application after parsing json data i want to send the data from one activity to another activity with the help of intents. but in my second activity it shows only last array json data. it is not showing all the  json parsed data in second activity.

first activity:

```
  private    class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SearchActivity.this, "", "");
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            String response;

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                 nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FromCityid",fromcity_bus));
                 nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Tocityid",tocity_bus));
                 nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DOJ",journey_bus));
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity httpEntity = responce.getEntity();

                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                Log.d("response is", response);

                return new JSONObject(response);

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
           // Log.v("TAG_RESULT",""+result);

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if(result != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONObject jobj = result.getJSONObject("Response");
                    String message = jobj.getString("Message");
                    String issuceess = jobj.getString("IsSuccess");
                    Log.v("TAG_Message",""+message);
                    Log.v("TAG_Message",""+issuceess);
                    if(issuceess.equals("true"))

                    {
                         JSONArray routearray = result.getJSONArray("Route");
                         for(int i = 0; i<routearray.length(); i++)
                         {
                              companyid = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("CompanyId");
                            CompanyName = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("CompanyName"); 
                            deptime = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("DepTime");
                             routeScheduleId = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("RouteScheduleId");  
                            arrtime =routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ArrTime");
                             fare =routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fare");  
                            hasac = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasAC");
                             hasnac = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasNAC");  
                            hasseater = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasSeater");
                            hassleeper = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasSleeper"); 
                             isvolvo = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("IsVolvo");  
                           buslabel = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString( "BusLabel"); 
                           avaliableseats = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("AvailableSeats"); 
                          bustypename = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("BusTypeName"); 

                         Intent intent=new Intent(SearchActivity.this,FromtoActivity.class);
                         intent.putExtra("COMPANYNAME", CompanyName);
                         Log.v("TAG_COMPANYNAME",""+CompanyName);
                         intent.putExtra("COMPANYID", companyid);
                         intent.putExtra("BUSFARE", fare);
                         intent.putExtra("BUSLABEL", buslabel);
                         intent.putExtra("BUSTYPENAME", bustypename);
                         intent.putExtra("AVALIABLESEATS", avaliableseats);
                        // intent.putExtra("arrayListIdentifier",);
                                    startActivity(intent);



                         }

                    }


                }   
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

secondActivity:

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String company_name = intent.getStringExtra("COMPANYNAME");
   String company_id = intent.getStringExtra("COMPANYID");
   String bus_fare = intent.getStringExtra("BUSFARE");
   String bus_typename = intent.getStringExtra("BUSTYPENAME");
   String bus_label = intent.getStringExtra("BUSLABEL");
   String avaliable_seats = intent.getStringExtra("AVALIABLESEATS");

   BusData bs = new BusData();

   bs.setCompanyname(company_name);
   bs.setCompanyid(company_id);
   bs.setFare(bus_fare);
   bs.setBuslabel(bus_label);
   bs.setBustypename(bus_typename);
   bs.setAvaliableseats(avaliable_seats);
   bdata.add(bs);
   BusDataAdapter  adapter = new BusDataAdapter(this, bdata);
   fromto.setAdapter(adapter);
```

fromto is a listview.

the size of bdata is 1.

Comment: please share the code and the Json String

Comment: same way you would send other type of data with intent

Comment: Post your JSON parse Code.Then only you get the correct solution.

Comment: Add all data in Object ArrayList then out side the for loop put your array list object in intent

Comment: ArrayList<BusData> bData = new ArrayList<BusData>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bundle to pass the value from current activity to next acivity

**Current Activtiy to pass data**

```
  if(issuceess.equals("true"))
 {

     Intent intent=new Intent(SearchActivity.this,FromtoActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("json_objcet", result.toString());//result is a json object
     startActivity(intent);

 }
```

**In Next activity to receive data**

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
     String json_object = intent.getStringExtra("json_objcet");
     try
     {




     JSONObject  result =  new JSONObject(json_object);
     JSONArray routearray = result.getJSONArray("Route");
     for (int i = 0; i < routearray.length(); i++) {

         String companyid = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("CompanyId");
         String CompanyName = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("CompanyName");
         String deptime = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("DepTime");
         String routeScheduleId = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("RouteScheduleId");
         String arrtime = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ArrTime");
         String fare = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fare");
         String hasac = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasAC");
         String hasnac = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasNAC");
         String hasseater = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasSeater");
         String hassleeper = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasSleeper");
         String isvolvo = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("IsVolvo");
         String buslabel = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("BusLabel");
         String avaliableseats = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("AvailableSeats");
         String bustypename = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("BusTypeName");

         BusData bs = new BusData();                            
         bs.setCompanyname(CompanyName);
         bs.setCompanyid(companyid);
         bs.setFare(fare);
         bs.setBuslabel(buslabel);
         bs.setBustypename(bustypename);
         bs.setAvaliableseats(avaliableseats);

         bdata.add(bs);
        }



     BusDataAdapter  adapter = new BusDataAdapter(this, bdata);
     fromto.setAdapter(adapter);
     }




     catch (Exception e) 
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code
first activity

```
private    class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    ArrayList<BusData> arrayBusData = new ArrayList<BusData>();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

     progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SearchActivity.this, "", "");
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        String response;

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
             nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FromCityid",fromcity_bus));
             nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Tocityid",tocity_bus));
             nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DOJ",journey_bus));
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = responce.getEntity();

            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.d("response is", response);

            return new JSONObject(response);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       // Log.v("TAG_RESULT",""+result);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if(result != null)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject jobj = result.getJSONObject("Response");
                String message = jobj.getString("Message");
                String issuceess = jobj.getString("IsSuccess");
                Log.v("TAG_Message",""+message);
                Log.v("TAG_Message",""+issuceess);
                if(issuceess.equals("true"))

                {
                     JSONArray routearray = result.getJSONArray("Route");
                     for(int i = 0; i<routearray.length(); i++)
                     {
                          companyid = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("CompanyId");
                        CompanyName = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("CompanyName"); 
                        deptime = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("DepTime");
                         routeScheduleId = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("RouteScheduleId");  
                        arrtime =routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ArrTime");
                         fare =routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fare");  
                        hasac = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasAC");
                         hasnac = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasNAC");  
                        hasseater = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasSeater");
                        hassleeper = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HasSleeper"); 
                         isvolvo = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("IsVolvo");  
                       buslabel = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString( "BusLabel"); 
                       avaliableseats = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("AvailableSeats"); 
                      bustypename = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("BusTypeName"); 

                      BusData bData = new BusData(companyid,CompanyName,fare,buslabel,bustypename,avaliableseats,);
                      arrayBusData.add(bData);




                     }
                     Intent intent=new Intent(SearchActivity.this,FromtoActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("bus_data", arrayBusData);
                    intent.putExtras(bundleObject);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            }   
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

second activity

```
      ArrayList<BusData> arrayBusData = new ArrayList<BusData>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundleObject = getIntent().getExtras();
    arrayBusData = (ArrayList<BusData>) bundleObject
            .getSerializable("requestProductItem");

    BusDataAdapter  adapter = new BusDataAdapter(this, arrayBusData);
       fromto.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

BusData class   also create constructor in BusData class

```
 public class BusData implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```